# Using receiver's infix function in lambda (for a DSL)

Tags: kotlin

I'm working on creating a DSL using Kotlin, and I was hoping to utilize a receiver object with an infix function to get that groovy DSL feeling.  I will start with an example of the syntax I am after:

> myDslFunction { myReceiversInfixFunc "some string" }

My plan for achieving this was this code:

```
fun myDslFunction(builderFunction: MyReceiverObject.() -> Unit) {
    val receiver = MyReceiverObject()
    builderFunction(receiver)
    // do something with receiver
}

class MyReceiverObject {
    infix fun myReceiversInfixFunc(someString: String) {
        // do something with someString
    }
}
```

The function and class snippets above compiles fine, but the DSL syntax listed above doesn't.  Here are some test functions I wrote to test the compilation:

```
fun test() {
    // desired syntax
    myDslFunction {
        myReceiversInfixFunc "some string" // doesn't compile
    }

    // not-desired syntax that compiles and works...
    myDslFunction { 
        this myReceiversInfixFunc "some string" // does compile
    }
}
```

The key difference here is the addition of the `this` keyword to setup the infix notation, but I would suggest that is undesired, and defeats the purpose of using the receiver object.

Is there something obvious I am missing here?  Can I achieve my desired syntax?  I wouldn't be surprised if I am overlooking a Kotlin convention to assist with doing this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot achieve this syntax, because Kotlin only supports `infix` function calls where the receiver is explicitly specified: `this myReceiversInfixFunc "someString"`.

There's a (quite old) language feature request for this syntax: [KT-1292](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-1292).